# Assign Public IP Address from Stopped VM to new VM

Tags: azure

I have a stopped(deallocated) VM with reserved public IP. I need to utilize the same IP for a new VM. I used ARM to reserve Public IP address. How can I do that? I'll be rally thankful if someone can help/point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/#how-to-associate-a-reserved-ip-to-a-new-cloud-service

Answer (score 0):

ARM VMs have Public IPs associated to their network cards (NICs) therefore you have two options to re-use the Public IP:

1. Remove (dis-associate) the Public IP from the NIC and assign it to another VM's NIC
2. Remove the NIC from the Stopped VM and assign that to another VM